# How to run .NET framework project with VS Code, which has dependency of ReactJS?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, .net, visual-studio-code

I am beginner to .NET framework and ReactJS. I have a code repository which is .NET framework, with ReactJS dependency.
When I opened the repository, VS Code suggested me to install C# extension, I installed.
Now when I opened the main file abc.csproj; it automatically started installing packages.
It ended with message:

```
Finished
Failed to spawn 'dotnet --info'
```

and notified:

```
The .NET core SDK cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on path.
```

What is process and list of extensions if I need it to be ran in VS Code?

P. S. It is a .NET framework 4.5 project and not core .NET project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you don't have the .net framework SDK installed on your machine.
you can download and install .net sdk from here : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks to be able to build .net framework projects

Answer (score 2):

The C# extension no longer ships with an included Mono & MSBuild Tools...

If you still need Unity or .NET Framework support, you can set
**omnisharp.useModernNet** to **false**
in your VS Code settings and restart OmniSharp.

See issue #5120 for more details.
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5120

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use Microsoft Visual Studio. I am using it and it's good and dragless rather than getting SDKs and having installation troubles.